# With websocket, the connection is closed in about 30 seconds even though we are communicating every few seconds

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket

I am creating a web application using websocket.
Currently, we start the connection from JavaScript with `new WebSocket ('wss: // {hostname}')` and after `onOpen` method is called, we can communicate with the server with `send` method and `onmessage` event handler several times.
However, even though it is not in no communication state, `onClose` will always occur around 30 seconds and the connection will be disconnected.
However, this problem does not occur while doing websocket with localhost 's AP server in PC development environment.
If you can not even connect, or Timeout when there is no communication status, etc., you have seen various solutions, but what kind of cause can be thought of in the situation like me Cow.
Thank you.

Comment: Is your server environment (hosting environment and NGINX configuration) configured to allow long running server processes and long running webSocket connections?

Comment: Since I am registering and using the server environment on the cloud, I can not refer to or update the settings on the server side. I can only deploy the application. However, when asking the server administrator about the timeout, it was told that timeout setting is not done.

Comment: Well, the browser isn't closing your connection on its own.  So, its either the server or some piece of network infrastructure between client and server, like a proxy, router or firewall.

Comment: How to you handle the web sockets server side what programming language do you use?

Comment: programming language: swift 4.  
web sockets server: Vapor cloud (Vapor 3) .   
Since it is not so famous, there is little information.
Since Vapor's community does not give clear answers, I also want advice from JavaScript and server side technician's point of view.